# I use FCM in Android, but I can't generate a token

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have use FCM in my Android application, but I can't fetch a token from `FirebaseMessagingService`.

I have this code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    //Calling method to generate notification
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

but this class is not called. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

The [`FirebaseMessageService`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService) is the class responsible for communicating with FCM. Often with receiving the message payloads and is **not** responsible for generating the Registration Token.

In order to get the corresponding Registration Token, just call [`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getToken()) in your MainActivity's `onCreate()`. You should also monitor the event wherein a token changes in `onTokenRefresh()`.

For more details, read through the [Access the device registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can this method in any where in your `String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`

Comment: Fcm remove the constraints to use in onCreate, freely use it anywhere.

Comment: it's given first time on application is run on device then this class is not run so what i do ?

Comment: i am sorry i do not understand your question.

Comment: When i run application in my device so i got first time Token but when i run again app's its i not got Token so what i do Sir